# Detecting certain HTML Code and automatically Removing it?

Tags: html, greasemonkey

Basically, I'm curious if it is all possible to detect certain HTML code, and remove it when found (Assume I cannot modify the server-side code). Either in combination with Grease/TamperMonkey, or by other methods. Is what I am describing possible? How easy is it to achieve?

Thanks for taking the time to read!

Comment: Short answer, yes. Greasemonkey allows for JavaScript to edit the page upon request.
[Documentation Link](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#The_Code)

Comment: I'd say you can find lots of examples in a couple of minutes via googling. Anyway, to make your question answerable you should edit it and add actual details.

Comment: I obviously tried google first. It was inconclusive, although it could've been what I was typing that made it inconclusive